# Text to speech & highlight text on iOS - karaoke program

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I have a problem with my iPhone app. I have a text file and I use text-to-speech engine to **read**  and **highlight** the word on screen.

The TTS engine can read sentences like human but I don't know how to highlight the word that is reading.

If I read the text word-by-word and highlight it, it will not natural.

(**This program like karaoke, but I use human's voice instead of background music.**)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know a **karaoke editor program** which I can record my voice and use it to highlight the reading text. (the output will be a video file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight text while Text to Speech is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624494/highlight-text-while-text-to-speech-is-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Karafun editor to synchronize voice and highlight text to video file but It's ugly way