# Highlight text while Text to Speech is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, text-to-speech

I am developing an app for ipad in which i want to add functionality as below:-

[image]

When user'll tap on play button Text to speech will start to play that Text at that time, that word will be highlighted as they are being read.

I know about in built feature of iOS but i want to do it programatically.

I searched a lot and got as below:

[Link 1](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts)

[Link 2](http://www.politepix.com/openears/#OpenEars_free_speech_recognition_and_speech_synthesis_for_the_iPhone)

[Link 3](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts)

If anyone know any API or any inbuilt framework. Let me know.

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the brilliant text-to-speech library inbuilt with iOS 7 onwards called AVSpeechSynthesizer.

You can control the speech as well as get notifications of it's progress using the AVSpeechSynthesizer delegate methods. The method that should help you achieve your desired functionality should be the 
[`speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate/speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:) method.

Have a look at the [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVSpeechSynthesizer) as well as the [AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate) API reference.

This [post](http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/) by Matt Thompson on NSHipster features the exact same functionality with an example.

Comment: Okk.. I ll try and reply you soon.

Comment: Is there any setting in that.? I download that project and it was not working.

Comment: I am not sure, haven't tried it out myself. However the code is pretty simple, you can implement it within a few minutes.